# redux-form input type number returns string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux-form

redux-form input type is returning string , it should have returned number

[Replicated problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/6jjp4o8rjr)

so i used parse to convert it to number

```
      <Field
        name="age"
        parse={value => Number(value)}
        component="input"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Age"
      />
```

Note : In redux form it Shows string

**But the problem is it does let us remove last DIGIT ZERO**

[image]

Comment: If you comment parse you get `undefined` for the first time. Do you just want to remove 0 only?

Comment: @AnkushRishi yes

Comment: doing so it will be shown as number in redux-form

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `Number('') return 0`. So Instead of setting the parse attribute to Field, you could just parse the value wherever you need

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div>
    {age ? <div>{typeof Number(age)} {`${age}`}</div>: null}
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Age</label>
    <div>
      <Field
        name="age"
        component="input"
        type="number"
        placeholder="Age"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2woojwv35r)**

Comment: actually i will have to parse it on multiple places, it will do lots of code clutter, so i am thinking `parse={value => Num` ON ONE PLACE as better option

Comment: In that case you wouldn't be able to avoid the `0`. You would need to parse where you are using it, so somehow store the parsed value.